# How to append to first child jquery

Tags: jquery, html

So im givin this site and I have to write this block of jquery to modify it. I can't edit the HTML but I can edit the jquery. I just cant figure out how to only add a `<ul>` only under `<li>tortilla</li>` and not the the other lists. When i run the jquery below with the second line commented out it works but also edits every other `<li>`. How woyld i be able to just append to the first child only and then delete the other `<li>` lists other then the one tortilla. Thank you my preferred output is below as well

**ingredients**

1.tortilla

- rice
- beans
- steak
- lettuce
- cheese
- tomatoes
- guacamole
- sour cream

this is the Html code i have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Burrito</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>ingredients</h2>
    <ol>
    <li>tortilla</li>
    <li>rice</li>
    <li>beans</li>
    <li>steak</li>
    <li>lettuce</li>
    <li>cheese</li>
    <li>tomatoes</li>
    <li>guacamole</li>
    <li>sour cream</li>
    </ol>


    </body>
</html>
```

this is my jquery code i have so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // $("ol li:first-child").addClass("tortilla");
    $("li").append("<ul></ul");
    $("ul").append("<li>rice</li>");
    $("ul").append("<li>beans</li>");
    $("ul").append("<li>steak</li>");
    $("ul").append("<li>lettuce</li>");
    $("ul").append("<li>cheese</li>");
    $("ul").append("<li>tomatoes</li>");
    $("ul").append("<li>guacamole</li>");
    $("ul").append("<li>sour cream</li>");
```

});

Comment: Are you sure you want to append all these things explicitly? It looks like you just need to move all the LIs except the first down a level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. There's no `<span>`, just an `<li>`, so you should select that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ol > li:first-child").append($("<ul>").
        .append("<li>rice</li>")
        .append("<li>beans</li>")
        .append("<li>steak</li>")
        ...
        .append("<li>sour cream</li>"));
    $("ol > li:not(:first-child)").remove();
});
```

Another way you can do this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ul = $("<ul>");
    ul.append($("ol li:not(:first-child)")).appendTo("ol > li:first-child");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Xp3Cj/3/)

This second version just moves all the list items after the first into a `<ul>` under the first one.

Comment: The OP also wants to delete the other `li`'s.

Comment: How would i delete the other useless `li`'s

Comment: I've added that to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Target the first li using either `li:first-child` or `$('li').first()`, then append 'ul',and `find()` the `ul` just added, then append all the new `li`'s. Here is how you do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').first() /* or $("li:first-child") */
    .append( '<ul/>' ).find( 'ul' )
    .append("<li>rice</li>")
    .append("<li>beans</li>")
    .append("<li>steak</li>")
    .append("<li>lettuce</li>")
    .append("<li>cheese</li>")
    .append("<li>tomatoes</li>")
    .append("<li>guacamole</li>")
    .append("<li>sour cream</li>")
    .end().siblings().remove();
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8vU5/1/)

**EDIT**

Please note that this has been updated to remove the other `li`'s and the demo is updated.

Comment: .first() is what I need to get mine to work. Forgot about that one. Especially when I am working with DIV elements, not a list. :first-child did not work.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CgEDn

This grabs the existing list and creates what you need.

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd take the time to post an alternative approach:

```
// caching a reference to the first li element:
var tortilla = $('ol > li:first-child');

// starting from that first li element:
tortilla
// getting all following sibling elements:
.nextAll()
// wrapping those siblings in a <ul>:
.wrapAll('<ul></ul>')
// wrapAll returns the wrapped elements, so we move from the wrapped
// <li> elements to the new parent <ul>:
.closest('ul')
// append that newly-created <ul> to the first (cached) li element:
.appendTo(tortilla);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BRsK9/).

This approach takes the siblings and moves them, which avoids the necessity of deleting any elements.

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).